# How to remove this red and green cross in Altuim?

Tags: altium

[image]

I was trying to design PCB in Altium and stuck in this.
As you can see in the image I'm not able to pin properly. Please help to solve this.

Comment: I expect that you have a room active off screen to the right. Zoom out fully to see if there is a  room at the edge of the black workspace. Delete the room. Every time you update the pcb from the schematic diagram the room will reappear. When an object is associated with a room, moving it out of the room is an error.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the online Design Rule Check in Tools > Design rules check

[image]

To temporary hide error marking you can use Tools > Reset Error Marker (shortcut T M)

To change the way Altium display error you can modify in Preferences > PCB Editor > DRC Violations Display

Answer (score 1):

That's the online DRC. I don't have Altium installed on this machine, so I can't show you the exact drop-down where you diable it but it is possible.